# How to get a certain line from multiple files in linux?

Tags: grep

I want to get a line where the first column has a certain string from 5000 files.

File 1

```
agd fkg fls  ofk
ggs kkg ikg  gkl
bsg ksf olg  lzj
many more lines,,,
kgf kkg ikg  lgk
```

File 2

```
gik zlg olg  pzk
ppl sjg gol  dzj
zjg iwj bmh  hgi
many more lines,,,
kgf wlg ugk  lkf
```

many more files...

Output files

```
kgf kkg ikg  lgk
kgf wlg ugk  lkf
more lines...
```

I want to get a line from each file, the line of the first column is a certain string, for example, "kgf" in this example.

I know how to get only from one file, but I could not come up with how to do from multiple files.
Could anybody teach me?

Comment: How do you get it from first file ? Show us

Comment: Just using grep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
grep -rEh '^kgf\b' .
```

It's recursive:

> -r, --recursive
> Read  all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links
> only if they are on the command line.  Note that
> if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.
> This is equivalent to the -d recurse option

Or using a wildcard in the current directory:

```
grep -Eh '^kgf\b' *
```

## Tests of compatibility:

- works well with GNU (not a surprise) `grep (GNU grep) 3.3`
- works well with FreeBSD 12.1 `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`
- Minix3 `grep version 0.9` have `-h` (and `-E` Extented regex and `-R` Recursive) switch, but don't recognize *word boundaries* `\b` but `-w`, so

`grep -wh '^kgf' *`

or

`grep -h '^kgf ' *`

Answer (score 0):

You can cat all files and pipe through `grep`

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | grep "^kgf"
```

or if you want to find in all the files in the directory, you can say

```
cat * | grep "^kgf"
```

If you want to look anywhere in the directory and the directories below,you can use

```
find dirname -type f -exec grep "^kgf" {} \;
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat` :)

Comment: Not really.  If you do a straight `grep` on a number of files, it will give you the file name as well.  OP did not want the file name in his example output.

Comment: So, how I can do without cat ?

Comment: `grep --no-filename "^kgf" *`. Caveat before someone points out the obvious: this will only work for something like 99% of `grep` executables out there. You can probably still get a hold of GNU `grep` older than this functionality. You can also run BSD or other `grep` implementations which use different command line flags. Or you could symlink `grep` to `echo` and have a laugh. But there is a very good chance it'll work.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Why are you even asking when [you already know the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592411/3645)?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Happy to be learning from the master.  Thanks.  Makes it worth being on this forum.

Comment: Added _test of compatibility_ in my post, `-h` switch is implemented even on Minix